# Starting with MongoDB FSGrids

Tags: mongodb

Similar to this guide [medium.com](https://medium.com/@richard534/uploading-streaming-audio-using-nodejs-express-mongodb-gridfs-b031a0bcb20f), I want to program a streaming server. But I do not know, how to store or upload my files to the database. I want to test, if I can stream a mp3 file, so I want to upload two files with gridfs. Can you help me by explaining how I can upload a file to my MongoDB via Gridfs?

Best regards

Comment: which version of mongo you are on?

Comment: MongoDB shell version v4.4.0, but I also have MongoCompass installed

Comment: Okay. I am assuming that you just need to put some tracks into your db so that you can follow along with that tutorial.

Comment: yes :) that is exactly what I want to accomplish

Comment: You can use `mongofiles` utility for that. I will put it in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked you version in comments because from version 4.4 `database tools` needs to downloaded separately. Earlier it was part of maongodb installation.

This is from official website.

> Starting with MongoDB 4.4, the MongoDB Database Tools are now released separately from the MongoDB Server and use their own versioning, with an initial version of 100.0.0. Previously, these tools were released alongside the MongoDB Server and used matching versioning.

- So go ahead and download `database-tools` from here :-

https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools?tck=docs_databasetools

- As you can see in the screenshot, you have all the database tools.

[image]

- Open new command prompt and `cd` to the location where you have downloaded database tools.
- From there run the following command. Replace `<DB_NAME>` with database name and `<PATH_TO_FILE>` with absolute/relative path to track you want to store.

```
mongofiles -d=<DB_NAME> put <PATH_TO_FILE>

e.g: mongofiles -d=testDb put C:\Music\1track1.mp3
```

- To verify you can connect to your Db using compass and check `fs.files` and `fs.chunks` collection.

Comment: Alright, I got it to work. Thanks a lot for the detailed guide, it helped me a lot!